# Understanding circuit with two BJTs where one has grounded base, and floating emitter

Tags: bjt

I'm trying to understand part of a circuit I'm reverse engineering.

Please see image. Purple wire is connected directly to a pin on a PIC, which is either an analog input or a digital IO pin (dependent on firmware, which I cannot reverse).

What is the purpose of this configuration of the BJTs?

[image: double bjt circuit]

Comment: Looks odd to me.  Not clear how Q1 would be in any state other than cutoff, even if current was drawn from the emitter of Q2.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look right, why is the drawing going off the edge of the page? Thought maybe diode at first but it would be reverse biased. Would need more context.

Comment: Schematic going off the edge of the page strongly suggests missing components to me.

Comment: Thanks guys. I agree. Very odd! It's a board that I'm reverse engineering. By tracing tracks on the board. Hence why going off the screen as I've just zoomed in on that part of my schematic. There is nothing else of interest except the purple wire that goes off to the PIC. The emitter of Q2 is not connected to anything. Base of Q2 is grounded. Could it just be a mistake on the part of the original designers and since it does nothing, it doesn't matter?

Comment: I would just double check part numbers and connections. Is this a commercially made board? It would be unusual to find a mistake like that in a production product.

Comment: If it's a 4+ layer board the emitter could be connected to an internal trace.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at a transistor and not a diode???   Diodes often come in SMT23 packages just like transistors

Comment: @AndrewBerridge Looks mighty suspicious to me. Here's what a commonly found [avalanche noise generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq2Np.png) looks like. Not exactly the same. But it makes me wonder if you got things worked out right. Some pinouts for certain BJTs were different from the usual pinout in the older TO-92. But I think the SOT23 is fairly standard. So maybe you got things right. Just wanted to bring that similar circuit to your attention. I otherwise don't see a purpose other than catching schematic-thieves. ;)

Comment: @jonk haha. Yes. It's a domestic appliance that's been out of production for 20 years and out of support for 10. The company is not even in the market any more. I want to add "smart" functionality to it. For my own amusement. I'm not 100% sure I have the right pinout or exact components right. It is a production board, but interestingly, there were no board revisions at all during the manufacture of the appliance. They made 100,000s of them. All the same.

Comment: I've checked it again. Components are marked 1DW - which appears to match BC846 and SOT-23. And I appear to have the schematic correct. Your thoughts about an avalanche noise generator are interesting! I wonder if it is some kind of noise generator to feed into an analog input on the PIC for pseudo-random number generation? Though I can't think why it would need a PRNG as it's not doing any crypto...

Comment: Hmm... no. It's as quiet as the proverbial church mouse on my scope! I reckon it truly is a mistake. I just can't see any sense in it at all! Thanks to all of you for your excellent comments thus far.

Comment: Tip: to indicate that a pin isn't connected in KiCAD, mouse over it and hit Q to place a no-connect symbol.